# How can I get Google Chrome to auto-fill more form entries?

Tags: google-chrome, autocomplete

Google Chrome's auto-fill does not work for most sites and does not save form entries. This makes it unusable. When I checked the options, I was shocked to see the only option with auto-fill is to save address and credit card.

Have they not considered the idea that form entries can be of different types?

Answer (score 3):

[According to Google](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?answer=142893), autofill saves more than just addresses and credit cards; saving names and emails works perfectly for me too. It just that the options menu doesn't list saving names and emails.

> Your address and credit card
> information can be stored in Google
> Chrome. The first time you fill out a
> form, Google Chrome automatically
> saves the contact information that you
> enter, like your name, address, phone
> number, or email address, as an
> AutoFill entry. The browser can also
> save your credit card information,
> with your explicit permission. When
> you enter credit card information on a
> form, Google Chrome asks you at the
> top of the page whether you'd like to
> save the information. Click Save info
> if you'd like the credit card to be
> saved as an AutoFill entry.
>
> You can store different credit cards
> and addresses as separate entries.

When you looked in the options, what you didn't realize is that name and phone number and everything are included in the save address thing. Click add address and you'll find out.

So it isn't Google's problem. It should work just fine. What version of Google Chrome are you using? The latest stable one should support it. Make sure that the autofill box in options is checked too. :D Take a look at the video in the "according to Google" link: it shows how it works. Kind of.

Comment: i am using 6.0.472. Its not working for me. It doesn't remember many form entries and it is hard to go back and forth filling everything. May be the browser is not smart enough to figure out what needs to filled in.. firefox works so well.

Comment: Considering the diversity of forms on the web, "names, emails, credit cards and addresses" is really not much more than "credit cards and addresses".

Comment: Even today, only around 50% of email inputs get an invitation to fill it in:(

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out my [Autofill extension](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/nlmmgnhgdeffjkdckmikfpnddkbbfkkk)? It has been working for a lot of people who found Chrome's built-in autofill feature lacking, so it might work for you also:

[image]

You will definitely have more power and control, and it will require one fewer click to autofill (or zero clicks).

Comment: Does it automatically remember data if the browser crashes? Can I go back and direct it to fill out the form "same as last time"?

Answer (score 0):

Check out my extension [Formbot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/formbot/ilnjaomgpkbmapjachcppgabkidbmnjc), you can set it up to fill your inputs with random data for testing purposes or else with predefined data.